# Какой знак пунктуации поставить? Объяснение

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги, тире

От лучезарного и вдохновленного (?) до созидающего и бегового.

Answer (score 3):

***От*** чего (или ***от*** какого, каких) ***до*** чего (или ***до*** какого, каких) — обычно в таких конструкциях между "от" и "до" никакие знаки не ставятся.
*От лучезарного и вдохновленного* — первая группа однородных членов, соединенных одиночным союзом "и"; *до созидающего и бегового* — вторая группа.
Между этими группами никакой знак препинания не требуется: от А и B до C и D.

*Цветок **от** лососево-розового **до** темно-красного, иногда двухцветный* (о тюльпане).

*Всё дерево золотистого цвета. **От** совсем бледного золота **до** глубокого почти тёмно-коричневого янтарного цвета* (Д. Калинина).

*Цвет — **от** нежно-голубого, зеленовато-синего **до** интенсивного густо-синего, васильково-синего и фиолетово-синего* (о лазурите); *Блеск опалов различен — **от** матового воскового **до** стеклянного и смолистого* (В. И. Марченков. Ювелирное дело).

P. S. Может быть, что в каком-то случае в указанном месте возможна постановка тире.
Но без контекста обсуждать эту тему (а также значение конструкции *созидающий и беговой*) нет смысла.